# Non specific band in EMSA gel?

Tags: molecular-biology, gel-electrophoresis

I am doing EMSA with Thermo LightShift Kit. I have a 150 bp biotin labeled probe which has been PCR amplified, gel eluted and sequenced. When I load samples on 5% native polyacrylamide gel, I see a non specific band in my control and samples along with suspected shift. Can anybody please help with an explanation of this band and possible troubleshooting?
Image Details:
Lane 1 and 3 are controls rest are samples
[image]

---

My binding reaction has HEPES ph 7.9, KCl, DTT, Glycerol, MgCL2, Poly (dI.dC) and NP-40 
Lane 1 and 3 are my negative controls ie binding reaction mix + labelled probe
Rest are binding reaction components mix + probe + nuclear extract
Nuclear extract was made using Thermo NE-PER kit
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more details on what your controls and samples contain? Are they positive or negative controls? Have you run DNA-only?

Comment: My binding reaction has HEPES ph 7.9, KCl, DTT, Glycerol, MgCL2, Poly (dI.dC) and NP-40 Lane 1 and 3 are my negative controls ie binding reaction mix + labelled probe Rest are binding reaction components mix + probe + nuclear extract Nuclear extract was made using Thermo NE-PER kit.

Comment: You could try running your probe on a gel by itself to make sure it only contains one species. Your labeling may not be uniform. You could acrylamide gel purify it before running your EMSA if it contains a secondary band. This should make the assay cleaner.

Comment: I did run just the probe and did not see this extra band. I ran the probe without poly (dI.dC) too and did not get any band as well. I am only get this when I run the probe with all components of binding reactions. I ran them alone without probe too to rule out contamination. Do you think it might be due to poly (dI.dC)?

Comment: Yes, my guess would be that your probe is non-specifically binding with the poly (dI.dC). You can probably eliminate this by playing with the salt concentration, adding 1% DMSO, or adding more detergent to your buffer.